# installation of firebird with inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, firebird

I'm trying to install firebird along with my application using Inno Setup but I have two problems that I haven't been able to solve:

1. When there is already Firebird installed in the computer, a message pops up during installation: `"An existing firebird xxx server is running. You must close the application or stop the service before continuing"`. How do I ignore this if you already have installed the Firebird? I tried several flags, more remains to message.
2. How do I get the installer to wait for the Firebird's installation to complete and only then run the application? Because the way I'm doing, it starts installing Firebird in the background, just do not expect to complete, and if the user has to click to open the program at the end of the installation, will give an error because the system still could not open the database because the firebird is still being installed in the background.

How to solve these two problems?

Comment: I check whether `Firebird` installed and its version. If the installed version is not correct I warn the user. If the version is correct, I continue the installation without installing `Firebird`. I'll show the code a little later.

Comment: Please ask one question per question, as it stands you are asking two separate things, making this question too broad.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the message "An existing firebird xxx server is running...." in InitializeSetup 
you may check whether Firebird server is running and its version.
If it is running and the installed version is not correct you may do something
(stop the instalation, or continue instalation without installing Firebird or something else).

**How to do it**

First You should find and download the files :

`FirebirdInstallSupportFunctions.inc`

`CheckIbaseFirebirdInstaled.inc`

and include them in code section:

```
[Code]
.....
#include "FirebirdInstallSupportFunctions.inc"
#include "CheckIbaseFirebirdInstaled.inc"
.....
```

In **InitializeSetup** :

```
function InitializeSetup():boolean;
var
  MsgResult : Integer;
  MsgText: String;
begin
   InstallSqlServer := true;

   //check for installed Firebird server version
   SQLServerRunning := IsSQlServerRunning;

   SQLServerInstalledVersion := GetSQLInstalledVersion;   
   case SQLServerInstalledVersion of
      0 : begin 
            if SQLServerRunning <> RUN_NONE then
              begin
                // there is an old version running ( InstalledVersion return 0 but server is running anyway)
                MsgText := '....message.........';
                MsgResult := MsgBox(MsgText,mbConfirmation,MB_OK);  //Show warning message
                result := false;  //Abort Setup
                exit;
              end
            else
              result := true;                 
      end;
      FB_INSTALLED_IS_NOT_VALID : begin
        MsgText := 'There is installed  ' + SummarizeInstalledProducts + #13 + 'This program required at least'+ '{#SQLServerVersion}'+ #13 + 'Do you want to continue?'  ;
        result := false;
        MsgResult := MsgBox(MsgText,mbConfirmation,MB_YESNO);
        if MsgResult = IDYES then 
          begin
            result := true;  //Continue setup
          end
        else 
          begin
            result := false;  //Abort Setup
          end;
      end
      FB_INSTALLED_IS_VALID : begin
        InstallSqlServer := false;  // The correct  Firebird server is installed 
        result := true;             //Continue Setup
      end
  end;
end;
```

**Used constants and variables**

```
[Code]
const 
  FB_IS_NOT_INSTALED = 0;
  FB_INSTALLED_IS_NOT_VALID = -1;
  FB_INSTALLED_IS_VALID = 1;
  FB_UNKNOWN = 2;

  RUN_NONE = 0;
  RUN_FB1_IB = 1;
  RUN_FB = 2;
  RUN_FB_21_25 = 3;
  .....

var 
  InstallSqlServer : boolean;
  SQLServerInstalledVersion : integer;
```

**Used functions**

```
//this function checks if Firebird is running
function IsSQlServerRunning : integer;
begin
  if FirebirdDefaultServerRunning then
    begin
      if RunningServerVerString = 'Firebird v1.0 / InterBase' then
        begin
          result := RUN_FB1_IB; 
        end;
      if RunningServerVerString = 'Firebird' then
        begin
          result := RUN_FB;
        end;
      if RunningServerVerString = 'Firebird v2.1 or v2.5' then
        begin
           result := RUN_FB_21_25;
        end;
     end
   else
     result := RUN_NONE;
end;

//Is this is a correct version
function AnalysisAssessment: integer;
var
  MsgText: String;
  MsgResult: Integer;
  VerString: String;
begin
  if ProductsInstalledCount = 0 then
    begin
      FirebirdInstalledRootDir := ExpandConstant('{pf}') + '\' + ExpandConstant('{#FirebirdDir}');
      result := FB_IS_NOT_INSTALED;
      exit;
    end
   else
     if ProductsInstalledCount = 1 then
       begin
         if (ProductsInstalled < FB25) then // See CheckIbaseFirebirdInstaled.inc ->ProductsInstalled const
            result := FB_INSTALLED_IS_NOT_VALID
     else
       result := FB_INSTALLED_IS_VALID;
   end
 else
    result := FB_UNKNOWN;
end;

//this function gets installed version
function GetSQLInstalledVersion : integer;
begin
  InitExistingInstallRecords;
  AnalyzeEnvironment;
  result := AnalysisAssessment;
end;


function SummarizeInstalledProducts: String;
var
  InstallSummaryArray: TArrayofString;
  product: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin

//do nothing gracefully if we are called by accident.
  if ProductsInstalledCount = 0 then
begin
  FirebirdInstalledRootDir := ExpandConstant('{pf}') + '\' + ExpandConstant('{#FirebirdDir}');
  exit;
end;
  i := 0;

  SetArrayLength(InstallSummaryArray,ProductsInstalledCount);

  for product := 0 to MaxProdInstalled -1 do
begin
   if (ProductsInstalledArray[product].InstallType <> NotInstalled) then
   //   result := result + intToStr(ProductsInstalledArray[product].ProductID);
   case ProductsInstalledArray[product].ProductID of
      IB4Install : result := result + ' Interbase 4' + #13;
      IB5Install : result := result + ' Interbase 5' + #13;
      IB6Install : result := result + ' Interbase 6' + #13;
      IB65Install : result := result + ' Interbase 6.5' + #13;
      IB70Install :result := result + ' Interbase 7' + #13;
      FB1Install  :result := result + ' Firebird 1' + #13;
      FB15RCInstall : result := result + ' Firebird 1.5RC' + #13;
      FB15Install  : result := result + ' Firebird 1.5' + #13;
      FB20Install  : begin
                      result := result + ' Firebird 2.0' + #13
                      FirebirdInstalledRootDir :=  ProductsInstalledArray[product].path;
                    end;
      IB80Install  : result := result + ' Interbase 8' + #13;
      IB81Install  : result := result + ' Interbase 8' + #13;
      FB21Install  : result := result + ' Firebird 2.1' + #13;
      FB21_x64_Install  : result := result + ' Firebird 2.1_x64' + #13;
      FB25Install   : result := result + ' Firebird 2.5' + #13;
      FB25_x64_Install  : result := result + ' Firebird 2.5_x64' + #13;
      FB30Install    : result := result + ' Firebird 3' + #13;
      FB30_x64_Install  : result := result + ' Firebird 3_x64' + #13;
   end;//case
end;
end;
```

**Update**

In **InitializeWizard** may use `InstallSqlServer` variable to show or hide "Install Firebird page" like this :

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreateActionSelectPage;
end;

procedure CreateActionSelectPage;
begin
  ActionPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
                                  CustomMessage('ActionPageName'), 
                                  CustomMessage('ActionPageDescription'),
                                  CustomMessage('ActionPageMsg'),
                                  False, False);

  ActionPage.Add(CustomMessage('InstallSQLSvr'));   
  ActionPage.Add(CustomMessage('InstallDatabase'));   
  ActionPage.Add(CustomMessage('InstallClientProgram'));  


  ActionPage.Values[0] := InstallSQLServer;
  ActionPage.Values[1] := True;
  ActionPage.Values[2] := True; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

wait for install_super.bat terminated

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\FB\bin\install_super.bat; WorkingDir: {app}\FB\BIN; Languages: ru; Components: fbserver database; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

Comment: Where is this file? I use another setup other than the .exe?

Comment: from Zip kit for manual/custom installs
http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/